# Fireevent.change does not change the value of the target element when used with Material UI Textfield

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, react-testing-library

I was trying to test if the value of the textfield(Material UI) component changes to the new value set. fireevent.change is not changing the target value of the input element. Is there any way to acheive that?

```
fireEvent.change(screen.getByRole("textbox"), {
      target: { value: "new-value" },
    });
   
     expect(screen.getByText("new-value")).toBeTruthy();
```

O/p

```
<input
  aria-invalid="false"
  class="MuiOutlinedInput-input MuiInputBase-input MuiInputBase-inputSizeSmall css-1n4twyu-MuiInputBase-input-MuiOutlinedInput-input"
  id=":r0:"
  type="text"
  value="Step1"
/>
```

The value attribute has not changed to "new-value"

The output says , cannot find an element with text "new-value".
How do I resolve this?